# batch script remove last word in file name or directory

Tags: batch-file

Can someone help me with a batch script. I need a script, who can remove last word and space in file name or directory.
**For example:**

**New folder** to be after execution of script **New** - remove last space and word.

Answer (score 0):

this should work `ren *" "* *" "`. Be careful though since this is going to change everything in that directory. If you know the 1st word of the file or folder then you can use this `ren 1stword" "* *" "`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%t IN (*) DO (
  CALL :process "%%~nt"
  IF DEFINED success ECHO REN "%%t" "!success!%%~xt"
  )
GOTO :eof

:process
SET "success=%~1"
:procloop
SET "lastchar=%success:~-1%"
SET "success=%success:~0,-1%"
IF NOT DEFINED success GOTO :EOF 
IF NOT "%lastchar%"==" " GOTO procloop
:: Remove any other trailing spaces
:rtsloop
SET "lastchar=%success:~-1%"
SET "success=%success:~0,-1%"
IF "%lastchar%"==" " GOTO rtsloop
SET "success=%success%%lastchar%"
GOTO :eof
```

This should do the trick for most "normal" names. It will possibly fail for names containing a very few characters like `!` and `^` - but such file/directorynames are silly.

Change the `FOR` to a `FOR /d` to process directories, not files.

Essentially, the `NAME` part of the ...name is passed to the `:process` routine in quotes to preserve its spacing, and the routine first lops off the final character until it finds a space, then continues removing any further spaces.

If the name has no spaces, `success` will be empty and therefore undefined, otherwise it'll have the new name.

After verification, change the `ECHO REN` to simply `REN` to do the renaming, this routine simply REPORTS what it intends to do.

---

Addendum:

We have a little terminological conundrum.

For `FILES`, `FILENAME.TXT` if often called the "name" of the file, but `FILENAME` is the "name" and `.TXT` is the EXTENSION.

When this process is occurring, the desired outcome is that `FILENAME WITH SPACES.EXT` becomes `FILENAME WITH.EXT` to preserve the EXTENSION or TYPE of the file.

With DIRECTORY names, the idea of an "EXTENSION" is still supported, so `Folder 18.9.0.17` is regarded as `Folder 18.9.0` with an extension of `.17` (the extension is whatever occurs after the final `.`)

The cure is quite simple - don't add the extension in the rename.

```
  IF DEFINED success ECHO REN "%%t" "!success!"
```

(but note that `Folder 18.9.0.17`, `Folder 18.9.0.18`, `Folder 18.9.0.19` will **ALL** have a target rename of `Folder` here - only the first may succeed...)

Comment: If it fits the bill, please accept the answer, and we're done.

Comment: :))) Can you help me little bit more, because when I tested it with normal name of folder like "New folder" was okay. I tested with my real folder names and they have a numbers with points like this "Folder 18.9.0.17". When I executed the script the folder rename is "Folder.17"  With files everything is perfect!